# Include branch into local machine

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub. Recently I created a repository and cloned to to my local machine using cmd. After that I created a branch apart from the master branch and tried to checkout but cmd displayed that there was no branch as such. Do I have to commit this new branch and push it ...if yes ...please care to say how?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything else. How did you create the branch and what is the exact error message?

Comment: pathspec 'gh-pages' did not match any file(s) known to git. These are the actual words shown in cmd. i created the branch on github platform using the known option of branch where master branch is there by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a new branch like this with cmd:

```
git branch myNewBranch
```

or

```
git checkout -b myNewBranch
```

You can push it to your repo by:

```
git push -u origin myNewBranch
```

Comment: This one will overwrite the branch he created on github though, I am not sure if it matters for his use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the branch on github and you want it on your local repo. You need to do 
`git fetch` and then you can do checkout.